# Prevent users to manually access to page

Tags: jsf, post, redirect, get

i have implemented jsf phase listener which check if user looged in or not, and if not redirect user to login page.

Now, i want to implement phase listener in case where user manualy input 
page name in address bar. In this case phase listener must automatic 
redirect user to login page and destroy session.

How do that in JSF ?

Comment: is your question about the fact that you want to differentiate betweens pages users navigate to by clicking and page manually typed in? Or am I not understanding your question right?

Answer (score 2):

Just use a simple servlet `Filter` which is mapped on a common URL pattern of the restricted pages like `/app/*`, `/pages/*`, `/secured/*`, etc. Here's a kickoff example assuming that you've a `@SessionScoped @ManagedBean UserManager`.

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns={"/app/*"})
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        UserManager userManager = (session != null) ? (UserManager) session.getAttribute("userManager") : null;

        if (userManager == null || !userManager.isLoggedIn()) {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml"); // No logged-in user found, so redirect to login page.
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res); // Logged-in user found, so just continue request.
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I say that i realase this. In situation when user logged in and try to access some page directly typing page in adress bar i want to block access page and redirect user to login page and destroy session. Is it possible to do ?

Answer (score 0):

I am on JSF 1.2 and did that this way:

```
public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) 
{
    FacesContext fCtx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    String actualView = null;
    actualView = event.getFacesContext().getApplication().getViewHandler().getResourceURL(fCtx, fCtx.getViewRoot().getViewId());  
    //actualView is the page the user wants to see
    //you can check, if the user got the permission, is logged in, whatever
}

public PhaseId getPhaseId() 
{
    return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;
}
```

Comment: This allows endusers to invoke JSF actions long before they are authenticated. I wouldn't call it safe.